# JPlayer set a custom duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer, shoutcast

I'm using JPlayer to read my ShoutCast audio stream. Everything is working fine, except that i want to show the duration of each song playing by my ShoutCast server.
I successfully get stream information, but i found nothing to change the player duration.

I tried something like `$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("option", 'duration', json.content['AVERAGETIME']);` but it's not working at all.

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks,
Navalex

Answer (score 0):

Since Shoutcast provides and endless stream (not separate files) - there is no way to get the "duration" for it. Some broadcasting platforms have additional APIs around Shoutcast providing more info about the current track, but in "plain" Shoutcast it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks but I didn’t asked how to get a duration, but how to set a custom duration to the jPlayer